# Send Data to Fragment from Activity with EventBus

Tags: java, android

I looked at all the questions and answers about this. But I could not find the answers to my question.

I have the `Fragment`: `MyFragment`. In it `button` and `textView`. I want to that When I will click on the button it will open `MyActivity` with two buttons: `cancelButton` and `saveButton`. When I will click `cancelButton` or `saveButton` finishes this `Activity` and `textView` in `MyFragment` will change to that what I send in `MyActivity`, for example "Cancel Clicked" or "Save Clicked".

What I did:

In `MyFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void onSaveEvent(Message message) {
    textView.setText(message.getMessage());
};

@Subscribe
public void onCancelEvent(Message message) {
    textView.setText(message.getMessage());
};
```

In `MyActivity`:

```
@OnClick(R.id.saveBtn)
public void saveClick(){
    finish();
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new Message("Save clicked!"));
}

@OnClick(R.id.cancelBtn)
public void cancelClick(){
    finish();
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new Message("Cancel Clicked"));
}
```

But it does not work I think it because when I start `MyActivity`, `Event Bus` unregisters in `onPause()` therefor can`t receive event

I tried with interfaces and it worked. But I want to realize it with `EventBus`

How can I do on `Event Bus`?

Comment: Well do not un-register it then..

Comment: @MuratK. terrible idea ... also it will obviously not work if you would enable "Don't keep activities" option

Comment: Obviously it is normal Activty to Activity comunnication ... the obvious choice is default Activty to Activity ... also you may read how to setup sticky events properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with a [StickyEvents](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/).

In `Fragment`

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(Message message) {
    Message stickyEvent = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(Message.class);
    if(stickyEvent != null) {
        tv.setText(message.getMessage());
        EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(stickyEvent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), you should register and unregister in onStart and onStop.
2. I think you should post events before calling finish() in your activity.